# ¿Agregar mas columnas en NOT IN MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Soy nuevo en el foro, me ha ayudado muchísimo hasta el momento. Pero ahora no encuentro una solución para lo siguiente:

Tengo una tabla en MySQL llamada "eventos" y otra llamada "vehiculos", la aplicación que estoy diseñando es para reserva de vehículos con PHP y MySQL.

La tabla `eventos` contiene: id, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, hora_inicio, hora_fin, usuario, vehiculo

La tabla `vehiculos` contiene: id, matricula, modelo, habilitado.

Cuando una persona va a realizar una reserva, el sistema ha de asignarle un vehículo automáticamente (mientras esté habilitado), pero para ello tengo que saber que no está reservado en eventos en el rango de fechas y horas que desea el usuario.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
SELECT vehiculos.matricula
  FROM reservas.vehiculos WHERE vehiculos.matricula NOT IN (
    SELECT vehiculo FROM reservas.eventosv
      WHERE '$aux_ini' >= CONCAT(fecha_ini,' ',hora_ini)
      OR '$aux_fin' <= CONCAT(fecha_fin,' ',hora_fin)
  ) AND habilitado='S' AND zona='Zona1' order by id asc LIMIT 1
```

Donde $aux_ini y $aux_fin es fecha inicio + hora inicio concatenadas y fecha fin + hora fin concatenadas.

Funcionaba correctamente hasta que se han hecho las reservas de todos los vehículos, ahora no se puede reservar ningún vehículo (aunque las fechas sean distintas) porque no hace caso al segundo `WHERE` (el del `NOT IN`) ya que solo me deja seleccionar un campo. ¿Alguna solución?

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

EDITO:

Haciendolo tal cual así, me devuelve todas las matriculas que hay en vehiculos, porque ya existen reservas de esos vehiculos en esas fechas, cuando lo que busco es que me devuelva una matricula que no esté entre esas fechas, por tanto hay solapamiento, no comprendo

```
SET @f_ini = '2018-12-12';
SET @h_ini = '12:00';
SET @f_fin = '2018-12-14';
SET @h_fin = '17:00';

SET @ini = '2018-12-12 08:00:00';
SET @fin = '2018-12-14 08:00:00';

SELECT vehiculos.matricula
  FROM reservas.vehiculos WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM reservas.eventosv
      WHERE eventosv.vehiculo = vehiculos.matricula
        AND (   (CONCAT(@f_ini,' ',@h_ini) > @ini AND CONCAT(@f_fin,' ',@h_fin) < @fin)
             OR (CONCAT(@f_fin,' ',@h_fin) > @ini AND CONCAT(@f_ini,' ',@h_ini) < @ini)              
             OR (CONCAT(@f_fin,' ',@h_fin) > @ini AND CONCAT(@f_fin,' ',@h_fin) < @fin)
             )
  ) AND habilitado='S' AND zona='Zona1' order by id asc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Vuelve a la primera versión y cambia el NOT IN por un NOT EXISTS, así no tienes que buscr una sola columna.

Comment: una aclaración ¿`eventos.vehiculo` contiene la matricula o el id del vehiculo?

Comment: Contiene la matricula

Comment: @Fly por favor checa la pregunta del OP me parece te ha dejado comentarios extra

Comment: @AdriánMenchero revisa la comprobación que he puesto, a ver si con http://sqlfiddle.com/ puedes aportar mas información

Comment: Editada de nuevo, espero que ahora si ;)

Comment: Gracias @Fly , observa la ultima respuesta que publiqué. Muchas gracias enserio!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no puedes agregar más columnas en el `NOT IN`, lo que se va a comparar con el operador `IN` es una lista de elementos. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Pero de todas formas creo que esa no sería una solución a tu problema. Tienes posibles fallos en la consulta que podrían hacer que no funcione como esperas.

- La comparación de fechas `'$aux_ini' >= CONCAT(fecha_ini,' ',hora_ini)` podría fallar dependiendo del formato de las fechas ya que estás comparando cadenas de texto no fechas.

Para evitar esto yo te recomendaría trabajar las fechas en formato **UNIX**, almacenado en un campo `INT`, tienes herramientas para tratar el dato tanto en php
(http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
y 
http://php.net/manual/es/function.time.php)
como en mysql (
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) y aunque es una lata convertirlo para visualizarlo le ganas velocidad (creación de indices) y sencillez (comparaciones, sumas y restas más sencillas)

Para salir de dudas verifica el resultado de la sentencia SQL con valores reales de `$aux_ini` y `$aux_fin` (muestralo por pantalla) o también ejecuta las pruebas (tras vaciar las reservas actuales) sin el `WHERE` de las fechas, creo que obtendrás los mismos reusultados.

(edito)

Como indica Miguel, la consulta se simplifica usando `NOT EXISTS` pero no por devolver más campos (realmente no queremos ninguno) sino porque se simplifica el búsqueda entre fechas.

<strike>SELECT vehiculos.matricula
  FROM reservas.vehiculos WHERE NOT EXIST(
    SELECT * FROM reservas.eventosv
      WHERE eventosv.vehiculos = vehiculos.matricula
        AND '$aux_ini' >= CONCAT(fecha_ini,' ',hora_ini)
        AND '$aux_fin' <= CONCAT(fecha_fin,' ',hora_fin)
  ) AND habilitado='S' AND zona='Zona1' order by id asc LIMIT</strike>

```
SELECT vehiculos.matricula
  FROM reservas.vehiculos WHERE NOT EXIST(
    SELECT * FROM reservas.eventosv
      WHERE eventosv.vehiculos = vehiculos.matricula
        AND (   (CONCAT(fecha_ini,' ',hora_ini) <= '$aux_ini' AND CONCAT(fecha_fin,' ',hora_fin) >= '$aux_fin')
             OR (CONCAT(fecha_fin,' ',hora_fin) >= '$aux_ini' AND CONCAT(fecha_ini,' ',hora_ini) <= '$aux_fin')
             OR (CONCAT(fecha_fin,' ',hora_fin) <= '$aux_fin' AND CONCAT(fecha_fin,' ',hora_fin) >= '$aux_fin')
 )
  ) AND habilitado='S' AND zona='Zona1' order by id asc LIMIT 1
```

Que sería:  Dame las `matriculas` de los `vehiculos` para los cuales no EXISTA un `evento` de dicho `vehiculo` entre las fechas buscadas.
<strike>He cambiado el  `OR` de las fechas por un `AND`, para buscar entre las fechas que quiero reservar.</strike> He añadido las tres coincidencias temporales donde se solaparían las fechas de los eventos con la reserva buscada.

Comment: Hola Fly, es lo que estoy probando, ademas ya no hago el CONCAT, lo hago con campos datetime reales:

SELECT vehiculos.matricula, vehiculos.orden, eventosv.fini, eventosv.ffin, vehiculos.habilitado FROM reservas.vehiculos LEFT JOIN reservas.eventosv ON vehiculos.matricula=eventosv.vehiculo WHERE ('2018-12-13 10:00:00' >= eventosv.ffin OR '2018-12-15 12:00:00' <= eventosv.fini) AND (vehiculos.habilitado='S') AND (vehiculos.zona='Zona1') ORDER BY eventosv.id DeSC

Comment: edité la respuesta, mira la nueva consulta.

Comment: Lo he probado como has dicho simulando unas fechas y horas que meteria el usuario:

SELECT vehiculos.matricula FROM reservas.vehiculos WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM reservas.eventosv WHERE eventosv.vehiculo = vehiculos.matricula AND '2018-12-13 09:00:00' >= eventosv.fini AND '2018-12-14 12:00:00' <= eventosv.ffin) AND habilitado='S' AND zona='Zona1' order by id asc LIMIT 1

Y me devuelve una matricula que tiene un evento del 2018-12-12 11:00 al 13-12-2018 12:00, es mas si le quito el LIMIT 1 me salen todas las matriculas

Comment: edité de nuevo..... creo que esta es definitiva ;) . Ante una reserva hay 5 posibilidades de las cuales solo dos no solapan fechas , creo que esta consulta busca correctamente los tres casos que solapan fechas.

Comment: Fly, funciona correctamente hasta que introduzco una fecha inferior al primer evento 
SELECT vehiculos.matricula FROM reservas.vehiculos WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM reservas.eventosv
      WHERE eventosv.vehiculo = vehiculos.matricula
        AND (eventosv.fini > '2018-12-10 09:00:00' AND eventosv.ffin < '2018-12-10 12:00:00')
             OR (eventosv.ffin > '2018-12-10 09:00:00')              
             OR (eventosv.ffin > '2018-12-10 09:00:00' AND eventosv.ffin < '2018-12-10 12:00:00')
             )
   AND habilitado='S' AND zona='Zona1' order by vehiculos.orden asc

Comment: Tienes mal los paréntesis del `where` en la fechas, tienen que estar las tres comparaciones dentro de un paréntesis con un `OR` entre ellas (basta con se se cumpla una de ellas).  **OJO** que cambié la consulta en la segunda comparación de fechas, repásala de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Lo conseguí de esta manera, comprobado

```
SET @ini = '2018-12-13 14:00:00';
SET @fin = '2018-12-14 12:00:00';

SELECT vehiculos.matricula
  FROM reservas.vehiculos WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM reservas.eventosv
      WHERE eventosv.vehiculo = vehiculos.matricula
        AND (  (@ini < eventosv.ffin AND @fin > eventosv.fini) OR 
                (@fin < eventosv.ffin AND @ini > eventosv.fini)
             )
  ) AND habilitado='S' AND zona='Zona1' order by vehiculos.orden asc LIMIT 1
```

Gracias a todos! En especial a @Fly

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido resolverlo de esta manera

```
SELECT eventosv.id,vehiculos.matricula, vehiculos.orden, eventosv.fini, eventosv.ffin, vehiculos.habilitado 
FROM reservas.vehiculos LEFT JOIN reservas.eventosv 
ON vehiculos.matricula=eventosv.vehiculo 
WHERE ('2018-12-13 10:00:00' >= eventosv.ffin OR '2018-12-15 12:00:00' <= eventosv.fini) AND (vehiculos.habilitado='S') AND (vehiculos.zona='Zona1') 
GROUP BY eventosv.id 
ORDER BY eventosv.id DeSC
```

El problema ahora es, que si un vehiculo ha sido 2 veces reservado en distintas fechas, si intento solicitar una reserva en una fecha que ya está reservado, me vuelve a asignar el mismo vehiculo debido a que se centra en las primeras fechas en las que se reservó y no en las ultimas.

Comment: No puedes agrupar, necesitas comparar todos los eventos, ni los primeros ni los últimos ¿que pasa si quieres reservar en una fecha entre dos eventos?